# Как склеить картинки по вертикали на php?

Tags: php

Есть куча картинок в папке images, как их склеить в одну по вертикали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php есть встроенная библиотека gd для работы с изображениями. Пример склеивания изображений можно посмотреть тут - http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2024. Правда здесь пример по  горизонтали, но отличается от вертикального только координатами.

Так же здесь приведен пример скрипта для склеивания картинок в скринлист - http://www.gofuckbiz.com/showthread.php?t=38727