# Как объединить 2 фото в одно

Tags: php

У меня например 2 фото, (2 разных файла)

первый

[image]

Второй

[image]

Как сделать из них одно фото с помощью php?

Я нашел этот код на форуме

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('image_1.png');
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('image_2.png');
imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
imagepng($image_1, 'image_3.png');
```

Запускал, менял 100 раз, все равно выводит это

[image]

Вероятно, они накладываются друг на друга. Но я не знаю, как сделать их в ряд по порядку.

Comment: Координаты поменять...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543954/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php